# How to save data inside room database when user exits app or just navigates back?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-room

I'm currently building android note taking application which uses MVVM pattern and Room for storing data.
Besides that I'm using dagger hilt, navigation component and lifecycle aware components.

Problem that I face is saving data when user exits the app or he navigates back from note fragment.
I want to achieve something similar to google keep note saving system. Google keep opens new window where you can input note title, description etc. but when you navigate back from that window note is automatically saved, and when you actually leave the app and close it completely, note is still saved. This is the behaviour that I want to achieve in my app.

What I tried to do is to save note variable ***in viewmodel*** inside ***onDestroyView*** callback and save it into database under ***onDestroy*** callback and this is the code that I wrote:

**onDestroyView code**

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()

    val title = binding.addNoteTitleEdittext.text.toString().trim()
    val desc = binding.addNoteDescEdittext.text.toString().trim()

    viewModel.note = Note(noteTitle = title, noteDesc = desc)

    _binding = null
}
```

**onDestroy code**

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    viewModel.insertNote(viewModel.note)
}
```

And this is the viewmodel that I use:

```
@HiltViewModel
class NewNoteViewModel @Inject constructor(
val notesRepository: NotesRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    var note: Note = Note()

    fun insertNote(note: Note) {
        viewModelScope.launch { notesRepository.insertNote(note) }
    }
}
```

This is my **Note entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
@Parcelize
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_title") val noteTitle: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_desc") val noteDesc: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_created") val dateCreated: Date = Date(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_tag") val noteTag: String = ""
) : Parcelable
```

But when I navigate back or exit the app nothing happens, note is not saved in database.

Comment: Do you want a realtime data saving, like save whatever the user is inputting to the fields while he's still editing it? if the answer is yes, use LiveData object and observe over it's changes, save/replace entity per each letter change!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use dagger or MVVM but I have used these simple method for store data in the room you can cover it after understanding this method

https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942

Comment: Thanks for the link but as I said I already implemented room with all these using mvvm pattern. Problem is not in the @Insert function because I can insert note into database with button click. Problem is I don't know how to handle situation described above. I tried it this way and it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have not set primary key in insert time so thing is that you can similar to SQLite set autoincrement true... see that  http://prntscr.com/1135uun  please vote after successfully task your completed

Comment: As I said I already implemented entity.
Here is the screenshot of it and I will also put it in my question:

https://i.imgur.com/D2QwHfW.png